# Getting my chrome extension to send URL of iframe to Google Analytics instead of window URL

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-analytics

I have a chrome extension which displays related pages from example.com in an iframe when people launch it while browsing other sites (let's say yahoo.com, for example). I have GA tracking code set up in the extension, but when the iframe launches, it's sending the URL of the window (so in this case, "yahoo.com") to GA.

How can I get it to send the URL information of the example.com page that is inside the iframe instead?

manifest.json:

```
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://www.googletagmanager.com https://ssl.google-analytics.com https://www.google-analytics.com/ https://www.google-analytics.com https://example.com; object-src 'self'; img-src www.googletagmanager.com https://www.google-analytics.com/ https://events.xg4ken.com https://beacon.krxd.net https://pubads.g.doubleclick.net https://sp.analytics.yahoo.com https://5237.xg4ken.com https://www.google.co.in https://s.amazon-adsystem.com www.google-analytics.com https://*.rfihub.com https://live.rezync.com https://secure.adnxs.com https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net https://www.googleadservices.com https://www.google.com https://trc.taboola.com https://www.facebook.com https://ad.doubleclick.net https://ext-inv-cdn.presage.io https://adservice.google.com/",
```

background.html:

```
<script src="../js/analytics.js"></script>
```

analytics.js:

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1', 'auto');
ga('set', 'checkProtocolTask', null);
```

Currently, the tracking code on example.com is this:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXXXX-1"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1');
if(window.parent)
window.parent.postMessage(window.location.pathname,"*")
</script>
```

Comment: Not sure if this helps but trying to work the other way round - track iframe on a page is almost impossible (when I tried about a year ago it was only possible if the iframe was from your own domain). 
My guess is, google analytics sends pageview hits before iframe loads (as it's JavaScript and probably loads as one of the last elements on the page). You can try to delay the GA script to make sure it fires after the iframe loads. And you will probably need to overwrite the location in the GA script. 
If you owned the domain of iframe perhaps you use "virtual pageviews" - send a fake pageview